# How to auto run bash commands after each git rebase --continue?

Tags: reactjs, git, git-merge, git-rebase

I am trying to rebase a branch onto a drastically different one. It's a React project. If I merge two branches brutally, I cannot even compile the code. Therefore, I am trying to rebase interactively.

While doing that, I want to make sure that after each rebase step the code base can compile. What would be a way to automatically reinstall `node_modules` and rerun the project (say I use `yarn start` to run the project) after each `git rebase --continue`?

Or if I am not on an ideal route, what would be the right way to merge those two branches?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way to do this is use [`-x`/`--exec`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#Documentation/git-rebase.txt--xltcmdgt) to run a command between each step. For example, if I do:

```
git rebase HEAD~3 -i -x 'npm run ship'
```

Then I see the following rebase plan:

```
pick <hash> <message>
exec npm run ship
pick <hash> <message>
exec npm run ship
pick <hash> <message>
exec npm run ship
```

In this case `npm run ship` is the command that runs all of the linting, testing, etc. to check that each commit is still good.

Note that the command needs to *succeed* (i.e. exit 0) for the rebase to continue, so make sure that's true of whatever you plan to do to check each commit.